# SF2 how to import css / js?

Tags: css, symfony, assetic

I'm currently working on symfony2 and I have a real problem with the "background-image" from my css files.

My problem is : SF2 doesn't load my js & css files when I use this "/bundles/dimiyvm/" method and I don't know why...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

    {% javascripts '/bundles/dimiyvm/js/*' %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}


    {% stylesheets '/bundles/dimiyvm/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    {% endstylesheets %}




ls -la /var/www/site.com/main.site.com/Symfony2/src/Dimi/YvmBundle/web/bundles/dimiyvm/css/
drwxrwxrwx 4 dimitri dimitri  4096 déc.  28 16:29 .
drwxrwxrwx 5 dimitri dimitri  4096 déc.  28 12:07 ..
drwxrwxrwx 7 dimitri dimitri  4096 déc.  28 14:53 classic
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dimitri dimitri   344 déc.  28 14:53 classic.css
drwxrwxrwx 2 dimitri dimitri  4096 déc.  28 14:53 goudy
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dimitri dimitri   901 déc.  28 14:53 goudy.css
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dimitri dimitri  1516 déc.  28 14:35 nivo-slider.css
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dimitri dimitri 27294 déc.  28 14:35 prettyPhoto.css
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dimitri dimitri 33207 déc.  28 16:29 style.css
```

I have maked:

```
rm -rf ../../../app/cache/* && phpsf assets:install --symlink web && phpsf assetic:dump && rm -rf ../../../app/cache/*
```

Thanks you very much for your helping !
Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make it relative: `bundles/dimiyvm/css/*` There properbly is not `bundles` directory in the root of your website, it's in `web/bundles`.